# reshape data with dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

Hy,
I have this dataset and I want reshape the data.

```
> dvd
   ID          Item
1   1   Sixth Sense
2   1         LOTR1
3   1 Harry Potter1
4   1    Green Mile
5   1         LOTR2
6   2     Gladiator
7   2       Patriot
8   2    Braveheart
9   3         LOTR1
10  3         LOTR2
11  4     Gladiator
12  4       Patriot
13  4   Sixth Sense
```

I want put the data in this format.

```
#     ID                                               V1
#  1:  1 Sixth Sense,LOTR1,Harry Potter1,Green Mile,LOTR2
#  2:  2                     Gladiator,Patriot,Braveheart
#  3:  3                                      LOTR1,LOTR2
#  4:  4                    Gladiator,Patriot,Sixth Sense
```

I know that I can do this with data.table using this code

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(DF)[, list(list(Item)), by = ID]
```

But I really want use dplyr package..
It's possible?
I'm thinking all day about this and I cannot forget this problem and it's killing me :)

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

With the dev version of `tidyr` ([install](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr)), it is simply

```
nest(DF, Item)
```

which would be

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Item = list(Item))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach is like so:

```
DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(V1 = paste0(Item, collapse = ", "))
```